# 3 monitor flickering mouse ubuntu 14.10

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, mouse, intel-graphics, 14.10

I've downlaoded ubuntu 14.10 on my pc..
I've got a 3 monitor setup (2 with my nVidia card, 1 with my intel buildin grapics)
But my mouse is flickering on my 2 nViadia screens.
I already tried to install the nViaidia 331 driver, but when i do that my intel screen don't work anymore.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks..